# navigationcontroller and tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

When I push a view controller vc4 on navigtion controller I can change settings of vc4 navigation item (title, barbuttons etc) but when I push vc4 in a tabbarcontroller and I change navigation item settings the changes are not displayed.

The Code below is executed, when I tap on a cell in a tableviewcontroller. the tableviewcontroller was pushed on navigationcontroller which is the rootViewController set in MyAppDelegate.

```
UITabBarController* tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
MyViewController1* vc1 = [[MyViewController1 alloc] init];
MyViewController2* vc2 = [[MyViewController2 alloc] init];
MyViewController3* vc3 = [[MyViewController3 alloc] init];

MyNavRootViewController* vc4 = [[MyNavRootViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]

                      initWithRootViewController:vc4];


NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, vc3, navController, nil];
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:tabBarController animated:NO];
```

Comment: Tab bar controllers are not meant to be contained within a navigation controller - tab bar controllers are meant to be the root view controller of your app.

Comment: If this is true the only way i can see to do what i want to is to have a tabbar as root  and hide/change the content of the tabs depending on which navigationview controller is active. This would be bad design from my point of view.

Comment: In Apple's documentation they mention presenting a tab bar controller modally, which may be a way to achieve what you want.  Here's a link to the documentation - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3.  Scroll down to the section titled "Creating a Tab Bar Interface."  Hope this helps.